# Error while working with Informatica Design SDK for creating mapping

Tags: informatica-powercenter, informatica

I have found the mapping sdk code samples, however without any documentation whatsoever.

Currently working with 9.0, I am looking for more info.

For one of the current issues, when I try to save the mapping to repository, (with pcconfig.properties lying in the same folder where the xml file is being generated), I am getting the following error:

```
Written the file..

Caught an exception in run() method

java.io.IOException: Cannot run program ""C:\Informatica\pmrep"" (in directory "C:\Informatica"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

java.io.IOException: Cannot run program ""C:\Informatica\pmrep"" (in directory "C:\Informatica"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

com.informatica.powercenter.sdk.mapfwk.exception.MapFwkOutputException: Error saving to repository :  Failed to connect to repository

    at com.informatica.powercenter.sdk.mapfwk.xml.XMLWriter.save(Unknown Source)

    at com.informatica.powercenter.sdk.mapfwk.repository.Repository.save(Unknown Source)

    at TestRaghavExample.generateOutput(TestRaghavExample.java:259)

    at TestRaghavExample.create(TestRaghavExample.java:64)

    at TestRaghavExample.main(TestRaghavExample.java:272)

Caught an exception in run() method
```

This is my initial example.. trying to find my way through the API..

Comment: Found the javadoc for the API in the meantime, however, its not much help. The documentation is really really minimal.

Answer (score 0):

The path to the `pmrep` utility doesn't look correct. It is normally found at the path `C:\Informatica\<version>\server\bin` on Windows.

Check the value of `PC_CLIENT_INSTALL_PATH` within `pcconfig.properties` is correct.